# How would I screenshot my extra desktop in C#

Tags: c#, screenshot, desktop

I am having issue's trying to get a screenshot of my other desktop. If you unsure on what i mean the link can be found here - https://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&rr=UC&a=https%3a%2f%2fdotnet-snippets.de%2fsnippet%2fdesktop-klasse-createdesktop%2f1248

I have tried the following code but still no luck. I have also tried executing a program on the secondary desktop and screenshotting the program and that still does not work.

```
    ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
// display image in a Picture control named imageDisplay
this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
// capture this window, and save it
sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\temp2.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Screen.AllScreens`

```
foreach ( Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens )
{
    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
    screenshot = new Bitmap( screen.Bounds.Width,
        screen.Bounds.Height,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );

     // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner
    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage( screenshot );

   // Save the screenshot
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(
        screen.Bounds.X,
        screen.Bounds.Y, 
        0, 
        0,
        screen.Bounds.Size,
        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy );

}
```

Comment: This still isnt working, I dont think you understand my question. Can you please visit the link i provided above? But thanks for your help.